# database imports csv file error: Error while importing data: UNIQUE constraint failed: StockPrice.stock_symbol

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to import a csv records into a database.

The following code is the database syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `StockPrice` (
`date` Date  NOT NULL ,
`stock_symbol` string  NOT NULL ,
`stock_price_open` float  NOT NULL ,
`stock_price_close` float  NOT NULL ,
`stock_price_low` float  NOT NULL ,
`stock_price_high` float  NOT NULL ,
`stock_price_adj_close` float  NOT NULL ,
`stock_volume` int  NOT NULL ,
`stock_exchange` string  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (
    `stock_symbol`
));
```

The csv data sample is:

[image]

The error of the database is:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The primary key of the table is `stock_symbol`. You are trying to insert more than 1 rows with the same `stock_symbol` and this throws the error. If you want these rows inserted you just remove that primary key from the definition of the table.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you defined `stock_exchange` to be the table's primary key.
It is obvious from the sample data that you want to insert, that `stock_exchange` is **not unique**.

What would make sense as a choice for the primary key (as seen in your sample data) is the combination of the columns `stock_exchange`, `date` and `stock_symbol`:

```
CREATE TABLE `StockPrice` (
  `date` Date  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_symbol` string  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_price_open` float  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_price_close` float  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_price_low` float  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_price_high` float  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_price_adj_close` float  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_volume` int  NOT NULL ,
  `stock_exchange` string  NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stock_exchange`, `date`, `stock_symbol`)
);
```